# Stereo component doesn't work, are there any alternatives?

Tags: aframe

i have a problem with the stereo component and the new aframe version, it just doesn't work. I am doing some picture galleries for stereo pictures. So i need a way to make them work. The stereo component just won't split in left/right. It either doesn't load at all or just gives the left eye image for both eyes.
Are there any alternatives to implement stereo pictures?
Also, for the future it would be much better to develop backgrounds with stereo pictures and then put in scene elements. I think there is a lot of potential for good sceneries.

Any help appreciated! :)
Cheers, Max

P.S.: I used every code example from the stereo component, just doesn't work at all. If my code is needed i can post it later.

Comment: Try filing an issue to the stereo component repo or asking the maintainer. Perhaps it doesn't work in 0.5.0?

Comment: Yeah, tinkered around a bit more. It doesn't work with any version after 0.3.0. And it doesn't like the sky, using a sphere instead works fine. The issue has been filed for quite some time in the repo. Too bad. Would love to know where the problem is. Guess i have to make a workaround for the missing components in 0.3.0 to get the functionality of 0.5.0. :|

Comment: [solved] The author just posted that he is going to look into it. Man i'm excited. Was about to start backtracking to get my menu back. Phew. :D